# $stateParams won't pass the values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass an object by a simple $state.go(), but all I get is default values 0 and ""

angular ui router:

```
placesApp.config(($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

    $stateProvider

        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "views/search-result.html",
            controller: "HomeCtrl"
        })

        .state("placeDetail", {
            url: "/place-detail",
            templateUrl: "views/place-detail.html",
            controller: "PlaceDetailCtrl",
            params: {
                placeId: 0,
                placeImg: ""
            }
        })
});
```

The link that triggers the function:

```
<a ui-sref="placeDetail" class="place-name" ng-bind="place.venue.name" ng-click="goToPlaceDetail()"></a>
```

Place detail function, I should not that this is not HomeCtrl. It is in a directive related to HomeCtrl:

```
placesApp.directive("placeGrid", () => {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        controller: ["$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", ($scope, $state, $stateParams) => {

            var imgObj = $scope.place.venue.photos.groups[0].items[0];
            var placeId = $scope.place.venue.id;
            var placeImg = imgObj.prefix + "1280x600" + imgObj.suffix;
            var placeInfo = {placeId: placeId, placeImg: placeImg};

            $scope.goToPlaceDetail = () => {
                $state.go("placeDetail", {placeInfo: placeInfo});
            };
        }],
        templateUrl: "views/place-grid.html"
    }
});
```

placeDetail controller:

```
placesApp.controller("PlaceDetailCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", ($scope, $state, $stateParams) => {

    $scope.placeId = $stateParams.placeInfo.placeId;
    $scope.placeImg = $stateParams.placeInfo.placeImg;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new `placeInfo` property. just pass the object.

```
var placeInfo = {placeId: placeId, placeImg: placeImg};

 $scope.goToPlaceDetail = () => {
   $state.go("placeDetail", placeInfo);
 };
```

And access the property like this

```
$scope.placeId = $stateParams.placeId;
```

**OR**

add a new property to state

```
.state("placeDetail", {
            url: "/place-detail",
            templateUrl: "views/place-detail.html",
            controller: "PlaceDetailCtrl",
            params: {
               placeInfo: {
                  placeId: 0,
                  placeImg: ""
               }               
            }
        })
```

Comment: Still getting default values 0 and ""

Comment: try the second approach

Comment: Still the same. Edit: My earlier comment was irrelevant

Comment: console `placeInfo` inside the `goToPlaceDetail` and check object values are assigned

Comment: instead of stateparam use `$state.params.placeId`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Have you tried something like:

In your `app.config:`

```
.state("placeDetail", {
            url: "/place-detail/:placeId/:placeImg",
            templateUrl: "views/place-detail.html",
            controller: "PlaceDetailCtrl",
            params: {
                placeId: 0,
                placeImg: ""
            }
        })
```

then in your `HTML`:

```
<a ui-sref="placeDetail({id:place.venue.id,placeImg:place.venue.name})" class="place-name"  ></a>
```

then in your `controller` (or where you need to get them from url):

```
placesApp.controller("PlaceDetailCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", ($scope, $state, $stateParams) => {


function init(){
    $scope.placeId = $stateParams.placeId;
    $scope.placeImg = $stateParams.placeImg;

}

init();
}]);
```